# basic analytical set of tools -- integration, differentiation, convergence and handling of applied maths equations

Tags: analysis, intuition, applications, machine-learning

I am more into mathematical logic, algebra, etc.

I am asking for a scrib sheet or short and precise collection of a set of tools which somehow demonstrates the everyday set of tools for integration, differentiation, convergence, etc. so the more analytical dirtier stuff ;-)

The question is inspired by reading "proofs" or calculations in applied mathematics like physics or machine learning. I think much of it is just getting used to it or assuming it to work like expected, but in these fields the steps are often too fast for me. I am concerned with differentiability or how to differentiate a skalar product or stuff while this level of detail seem infeasible since it would take ages to fill in these details in an everyday applied maths calculation.

So what I am looking for is for a good scrib sheet, which kind of presents the basic set of tool in a condensed way, maybe allowing me to learn the required intuition about this stuff.

I hope I managed to make clear my point, as I find it hard to express, what really makes machine learning proofs much more unintuitive or complicated to me thatn algebra proofs. For me it seem that I try to stick too close to rigour.